# Almost regular graphs that are Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

It is known that every $r$-regular graph on $2r+1$ vertices is Hamiltonian (**Nash-Williams** theorem, see [here](http://blog.vene.ro/2012/01/29/nash-williams-theorem-on-the-hamiltonian-property-of-some-regular-graphs/)).

Now, I wonder if there is a simpler way to show that the graph on $4n+3$ ($n \ge 1$) vertices with degree sequence $(2n+1, \ldots, 2n+1, 2n+2)$ is Hamiltonian?

("a simpler way" means not to use the arguments in the proof of **Nash-Williams** theorem [here](http://blog.vene.ro/2012/01/29/nash-williams-theorem-on-the-hamiltonian-property-of-some-regular-graphs/)).

For example, the graph with degree sequence $(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)$ must be Hamiltonian.

Comment: I do not know if there exist such result after the **Nash-Williams** theorem, but we can conclude the following corollary:  Suppose $G$ is a graph on $n$ vertices with degree of each vertex is either $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor $ or $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil $. Then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: Actually we were wondering about the same question. Have you found such a result in literature? Nash-Williams arguments seem to work, but are there any published results with or without using this argument?